# Using Map of CacheBuilder Object

Tags: java, maven, concurrency, guava, concurrenthashmap

I am having say N sites : Site1, Site 2, Site3..upto Site N.

Now, each site has its own tendency to handle requests and there is a config that says site X can handle A requests per B seconds.

So, there are workers that are hitting these sites continuously. If I were to do for a single site then a CacheBuilder would have helped.

But how can I do it for N sites.

```
Cache<String, String> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .concurrencyLevel(4)
            .weakKeys()
            .maximumSize(10000)
            .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build(
                    new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
                        public String load(String key) {
                            return "HEY";
                        }
                    });
```

In this the key could have been a messageID and the value can be the timestamp its been put.
Say a site X has 2 requests per 5 seconds. Then expireAfterWrite will handle this.

So ideally I am looking for a Map of this CacheBuilder, where Key will be the Site Name and value will be this CacheBuilder Object.

What can be an ideal data structure for the same if there is anything other than this ? If no, then how to modify it for this use case ?

Comment: When you say "site X can handle A requests per B seconds", what happens when you get A+1 requests? Is that when you fall back to the cache?

Comment: Assuming you're working with a predefined number of sites, why not keep a simple `Map<SiteName, Cache<MessageID, Timestamp>>`? Or if sites are more dynamic, use a `Cache` instead of `Map`.

Comment: @shmosel Then the earliest message that came should get removed from that site.